# How to circumvent MacOS Catalina Bug with reset to 100% Display Brightness?

Tags: mac, display, display-settings, macos-catalina

I have a **late 2015 iMac** running **Mac OS Catalina (10.15.4)** which drives me nuts, as it resets the **display brightness to 100% after sleep**.

I use the machine mainly for image processing - so I use a SpyderPro calibration tool to set the brightness and color profile to a setting that helps me to see neutral colors while in Lightroom and Photoshop.

I have deactivated auto brightness in the display controls, as well as deactivated nightshift.

The problem is, that having the display to a set brightness is vital for image editing. And I would not find the exact spot back without another calibration.

This bug seems to be pretty common, at least googling for it. However, I have not found a solution.

My question: *Is there a solution? If not, how can I work around the bug? Do you know if there is a tool that sets the display brightness to a numeric value? Some kind of shell script that I can use? An app that features switching between brightness profiles perhaps?*

Comment: Use EventScripts  and `brightness` command? Query info: `brightness -l` or `brightness -lv` Installed with Homebrew: `brew install brightness` Set `brightness 0.8`

Comment: Says "brightness: failed to set brightness of display 0x42b2cd8 (error -536870201)" - otherwise a good idea.

Comment: brightness -l
display 0: main, active, awake, online, built-in, ID 0x42b2cd8
brightness: failed to get brightness of display 0x42b2cd8 (error -536870201)
display 1: active, awake, online, external, ID 0x2b101b14
brightness: failed to get brightness of display 0x2b101b14 (error -536870201)

Comment: The issue seems to be known: https://github.com/nriley/brightness/issues/25

Comment: Ok, cloning the repo and building brightness myself resulted in a version that works. Thanks. Do you want to put that in the answer box, to get the upvote you deserve?

Comment: See `f.lux` for macOS https://justgetflux.com/news/pages/macquickstart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with help of STTR, I found a solution.

**Prerequisites:**

- Installed homebrew

**What to do:**

- Install brightness via homebrew `brew install brightness`
- Open a shell and test if `brightness 0.3` does dimm your screen
- If that works, continue with **how to make it practical**
- If you get an error message `brightness: failed to set brightness of display 0x42b2cd8 (error -536870201)` you need to compile brightness yourself. Continue with the next steps.

**What if brightness does not work?**

- make sure you have a git client installed
- Go to https://github.com/nriley/brightness and clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/nriley/brightness.git`
- `cd brightness`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`
- Test if `brightness 0.3` does dimm your screen. It should.

**How to make it practical**

- Open the mac Automator software
- Create a new Program
- Select `Run Shell Script`
- Insert `/usr/local/bin/brightness 0.3` Note: You can check if the path is ok with `which brightness` in the command line. Exchange 0.3 for whatever value works for you.
- Save as a Program
- Drag the program to your program folder
- Drag it into the docking bar

Now you can reset the original brightness with one click on the little robot icon and then start editing your images. Have fun!

Comment: inside the system settings inside the resources there is a `.plist` that is responsible for fine-tuning the brightness and color offset. In principle, dubbing and backing it up gives an accurate color reproduction. Unfortunately, I forgot where it is. In addition, to set the color after waking up the monitor, you need enough time from 15 to 30 minutes. Also, if you do not have a room in gray tones without natural light sources, you need to adjust the colors of the monitor. I advise you to use f.lux or switch color profiles depending on the lighting or time of day.